# Как сохранить пропорции матрицы при экспорте в jpg?

Tags: matlab

У меня есть небольшой скрипт, который импортирует матрицу из текстового файла, визуализирует ее и сохраняет в jpg. Матрица у меня имеет соотношение сторон 2:1, а файл картинки, видимо по умолчанию, сжимает до 1:1. Как сохранить исходные пропорции матрицы? Можно ли здесь применить функцию `truesize`?

```
files = dir('*.txt');
for i=1:length(files)
importdata(files(i).name);
h = imagesc(ans);
set(gca,'CLim',[-0.3395 8.3216]);
colorbar;
saveas(h,[files(i).name '.jpg'], 'jpg');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте или axis equal или axis image перед saveas. Другой вариант - вручную сделать изображение через gray2ind и записать с помощью imwrite